# training and testdata for data that changes over time

Tags: predictive-models, time-varying-covariate

i want to build a prediction model for the sale price of used phones(on ebay).
for that i want to split the data into a training and a test dataset.
Now here's the problem:

phones change over time. if i split i.e. my data into:
training data: phones from 2010-2014
test data: phones from 2015

For example the feature "ios 9"  that exist in 2015 don't exist in the training data. and if i take my prediction model that was built based on the training data, i wont be able to make predictions for my test data.
Further more i have to consider the inflation of the phones.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to split my data? or any other helpful advices

Thank you guys in advance

Ching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

(1) Do not split your data set based on time periods. But split the data set **randomly** into two groups. This way, the composition of both partitions are similar, and you won't have any significant discrepancies between the two.

(2) If your goal is to use the model **on an ongoing basis** -- i.e., to score future records to make predictions -- then I would suggest you discard historical data that are not relevant any more. For instance, if data from 2014 does not contain phone models that are prevalent today (and in the near future), then those time periods should be discarded from the modeling population.